# Webdriver in Ruby, how to check elements exist

Tags: ruby, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Webdriver in Ruby and I want to verify three text exists on a page.

Here is the piece of html I want to verify:

```
<table class="c1">
  <thead>many subtags</thead>
  <tbody id="id1">
    <tr class="c2">
        <td class="first-child">
            <span>test1</span>
        </td>
        manny other <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="c2">
        <td class="first-child">
            <span>test2</span>
        </td>
        manny other <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="c2">
        <td class="first-child">
            <span>test3</span>
        </td>
        manny other <td></td>>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I verify "test1", "test2" and "test3" presents on this page using

- find_element
- find_elements
- getPageSource?

What is the best approach for it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with `#find_elements` method,because with other 2 options there will be a chance to get *no such element exception*.

First collect it in an array -

```
array = driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//table[@class='c1']//tr[@class='c2']//span[text()='test1']")
```

Now check the array size

```
"test1 is present" unless array.empty?
```

The same way we can test for test2 and test3.

Comment: I got an error as c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:59:in `find_elements': cannot find elements by :xapth (ArgumentError)

Comment: @Eric now try.. I wrote it *xapth* instead of *xpath*.. :)

Comment: thanks for your reply. sorry I tried and it still doesn't work, the array size is always 0.

Answer (score 1):

Following sample code will help you to perform your task :

```
 def check_element_exists
     arr = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
     arr.each do |a|
     if $driver.page_source.include? a
        puts a
     else
        print a
        puts " Not present"
     end
 end
```