# Continue script if it doesn't find element

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am waiting for a page to load in Selenium like this:

```
 wait.until {
       comp = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//span[contains(text(), 'New Page']")
       if comp.displayed?
          myVal= "Passed"
       end
 }
```

If the new page doesn't load, it gives me a timeout error and the script does not continue. How can I make it continue if the element is not found?

Comment: This isn't the actual code but it compiles

Comment: Trying using a rescue clause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webdriver in Ruby, how to check elements exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393157/webdriver-in-ruby-how-to-check-elements-exist)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example modified from a project:

```
require 'logger'

logger = Logger.new('logfile.log')

begin
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)

  wait.until {
    comp = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//span[contains(text(), 'New Page']")

    if comp.displayed?
      myVal = "Passed"
    end
  }

rescue => e
  # log error
  logger.error "ERROR! => #{e}"
end

# continue with whatevs
```